# How to represent the column with max Nan values in pandas df?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

i can show it by: df.isnull().sum() and get the max value with: df.isnull().sum().max() ,
but someone can tell me how to represent the column name with max Nan's ?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter column with most missing values:

```
df.loc[:, df.isnull().sum().idxmax()]
```

If need select multiple columns with more maximes compare `Series` with max value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,np.nan,5,np.nan,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,np.nan,2,np.nan],
         'D':[1,np.nan,5,7,1,0]

})
    
print (df)
   A    B    C    D
0  a  4.0  7.0  1.0
1  b  5.0  8.0  NaN
2  c  NaN  9.0  5.0
3  d  5.0  NaN  7.0
4  e  NaN  2.0  1.0
5  f  4.0  NaN  0.0

s = df.isnull().sum()
df = df.loc[:, s.eq(s.max())]
print (df)
     B    C
0  4.0  7.0
1  5.0  8.0
2  NaN  9.0
3  5.0  NaN
4  NaN  2.0
5  4.0  NaN
```

Comment: If i have two columns with max val its represent me just one,

Comment: @bigish - Answer was edited, can you test?

Comment: Yes its work but i need to represent just the name of the columns please!

Comment: @bigish then use `df.columns[s.eq(s.max())]`